# How to use Ids returned from a mysql query inside another query in Python

Tags: python, database-cursor

New to python so need some help.

I have a mysql query which I execute using a cursor as below:

```
qresult = cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM questions WHERE category_id=%s, (category_id))
questionslist = cursor.fetchall()
```

This prints the questionlist as below:

```
[{'question_id': 1, 'question_text': 'How many servers run at max capacity?', 'category_id': 1
{'question_id': 2, 'question_text': 'Is the database getting replicated?', 'category_id': 1}
```

Now in the very next step, I need to run another query to get the choices for these questions using the question_id returned from above. Something like

```
cresult = cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM choices WHERE question_id in %s',(questionslist['question_id']))
```

However I get a attribute error - (questionslist['question_id'])) TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

This is confusing and when searched on google, I see some solution using a placeholders which I didn't completely understand. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: You seem to be simulating an sql join from python. Why don't you simply use a join instead?

Comment: with join the questions gets duplicated because of choices which m trying to avoid

Comment: Depending on the number of questions, that duplication may still be better, than launching separate queries for each question.